# p4dual-915gl битый PXE

Tags: bios, pxe

PXE загружается, доходит до TFTP и на этом этапе все рушится.
На других машинах все работает. Нашел следующий линк http://www.lissyara.su/articles/mad_hands/computers/bios+pxe/.
Идея вроде правильная, но ничего не выходит, не удается выдрать биос с матери.
Может кто подскажет какой нибудь выход.
Как починить или хотя бы утилиты для редактирования биоса (желательно прямо из под винды).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А секрет просто - нужно работать не с дампом из флэшки, а скачать прошивку с оф. сайта и ее курочить. В зависимости от типа БИОСа существуют разные утилиты для работы с ним.

Award -> CBROM

AMI -> MMTool

Phoenix -> Phoenix BIOS Editor

Зашить правленный БИОС из винды так же можно. Для этого существует целый спектр утилит. Для Phoenix обычно используется WINPHLASH, для AMI - AFUWIN, Авардовского флэшера не наблюдал. Но надежнее шить, конечно, под ДОСом.

Comment: Оказывается у меня AMI биос на тех машинах, поэтому ничего не хотело грабится. Собственно продолжая вопрос: я через /D (вроде удалить модуль) убил все родные PCI Loader ы и залил туда загрузочник который был на лисяре, вопрос это не убьет мать? Может просто добавить не удаляя ничего? Есть нормальный ман по этой утилите или гайд как правильно это сделать потому что она сложнее чем cbrom. Еще вопрос: если я таки убью биос, я смогу как то восстановить его?

Comment: Проблема скорее не в AMI, а в том, что это АСРОК (?). Некоторые фирмы отличаются ограничением доступа к БИОСа. PXE-модуль должен быть под конкретную сетевуху, чтобы он грузился. Т.е. должны быть правильно прописаны VendorID и  DeviceID + сам код должен подходить к типу чипа сетевой карты. Если БИОС убьется - его можно перешить на программаторе. Или все-таки попробовать "горячей заменой" на схожей мат. плате

Comment: PS: PXE-модули я вообще etherboot'ом делал

Comment: На этих мамках не вынуть биосы, поэтому и спрашиваю. Бутром от 8139 все правильно. Да и то что асрок добавляет косячности. Сетевухи интегрированные, я не уверен что у них свой бутром есть, скорее они как раз из биоса его брали т.к. в биосе я обнаружил 4 секции pci loader

Comment: 1 PCI ROM - videobios<p>
еще 1 PCI ROM - какой-нить RAID IDE/SATA-контроллер<p>
еще 1 PCI ROM - сам модуль сетевки <p>
Придумать за что отвечает еще один PCI ROM мне уже тяжело.<p>
<i>На этих мамках не вынуть биосы, поэтому и спрашиваю</i>
В смысле физически не вынуть? Тогда только паяльник + программатор<p>
<i>я не уверен что у них свой бутром есть</i>
Свой или интегрированный в БИОС бутром - разницы по сути нет

Comment: А все таки чем мне может грозить то что я дописываю в биос модуль для PXE? и может ли это его убить? и как правильно засунуть туда этот бутром что на лисяре выложен? очень не хочется накосячить

Comment: Помог Replace свежим pxe старого в биосе с помощью MMTool для windows.